# Heading with border-box

Tags: html, css

I want to have a heading inside a BorderBox div:

[ATM it looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2A8R.png)

This is my html code:

```
<div id="cert"> 
   
    <div id="wrapper4">
     
        <div id="innerLogo">
            
            <div><img src="./img/ccna.png" id="certImg"/></div>
            <div><img src="./img/linux.png" id="certImg"/></div>
            <div><img src="./img/azure.png" id="certImg"/></div>
        </div>
        <div id="innerLogo2">
            <div><img src="./img/javascript-1.png" id="certImg"/></div>
            <div><img src="./img/python.png" id="certImg"/></div>
            <div><img src="./img/powershell.png" id="certImg"/></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#cert {

    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    


}



#wrapper4 {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    

}


#innerLogo{

    width: 490px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-radius: 20px;


}

#innerLogo2{

    width: 490px;
    padding: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-radius: 20px;


}



#certImg{
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;

}
```

I want to have a Heading inside inner Logo div above the images.

I tried several things but all the time the heading is handles as a border bnox element and is placed left to the images.

Do you know any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex;`, `flex-direction: column;` and three divs with img as child put into one div with `display:flex;`.

```
<div id="innerLogo" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <div style="display: flex;">
          <div><img src="./img/ccna.png" id="certImg" /></div>
          <div><img src="./img/linux.png" id="certImg" /></div>
          <div><img src="./img/azure.png" id="certImg" /></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
 #cert {

      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 1000px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: left;



    }



    #wrapper4 {
      width: auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;


    }


    #innerLogo {

      width: 490px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: left;
      justify-content: space-between;
      background-color: #dfdfdf;
      border-radius: 20px;


    }

    #innerLogo2 {

      width: 490px;
      padding: 25px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: left;
      justify-content: space-between;
      background-color: #dfdfdf;
      border-radius: 20px;


    }



    #certImg {
      width: 140px;
      height: 140px;

    }
```

```html
<div id="cert"> 
   
    <div id="wrapper4">
     
       <div id="innerLogo" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <div><img src="./img/ccna.png" id="certImg" /></div>
          <div><img src="./img/linux.png" id="certImg" /></div>
          <div><img src="./img/azure.png" id="certImg" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div id="innerLogo2" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
           <h1>Heading</h1>
           <div style="display: flex;">
              <div><img src="./img/javascript-1.png" id="certImg"/></div>
              <div><img src="./img/python.png" id="certImg"/></div>
              <div><img src="./img/powershell.png" id="certImg"/></div>
           </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your logos in another `<div>` and set `display: flex;` to that div. The justify-content styling you had in your innerLogo & innerLogo2 `<div>` did not appear to be doing anything, but I needed to add both an `align-items: center;` & `flex-direction: column` to them.

CSS

```
#cert {

    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    


}



#wrapper4 {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    

}


#innerLogo{

    width: 490px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#innerLogo2{

    width: 490px;
    padding: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border-radius: 20px;
}



#certImg{
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;

}

.logoContainer {
  display: flex;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cert"> 
   
    <div id="wrapper4">
     
      <div id="innerLogo">
          <h1>Header you wanted</h1>
          <div class = "logoContainer">
            <div><img src="./img/ccna.png" id="certImg"/></div>
            <div><img src="./img/linux.png" id="certImg"/></div>
            <div><img src="./img/azure.png" id="certImg"/></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="innerLogo2">
        <h1>Header you wanted</h1>
          <div class = "logoContainer">
            <div><img src="./img/javascript-1.png" id="certImg"/></div>
            <div><img src="./img/python.png" id="certImg"/></div>
            <div><img src="./img/powershell.png" id="certImg"/></div>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow **#cert to act as a row** and **#wrapper4 as a column**, with the inner divs as columns.

Here's the result:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: #E4DDC0 ;
}

#cert{
    width: 100%;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
}
#wrapper4{
    padding: 5px;
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}

.col{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 30%;
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#certImg{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="cert"><!-- Acting as a row -->

<div id="wrapper4"><!-- Main Column 1 -->
    <h1>Heading Here</h1>
  <center>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png/A548FF" alt="" id="certImg"></div><!-- Column -->
    <div class="col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png/A548FF" alt="" id="certImg"></div><!-- Column -->
    <div class="col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png/A548FF" alt="" id="certImg"></div><!-- Column  -->
  </center>
</div>

<div id="wrapper4"><!-- Main Column 2 -->
    <h1>Heading Here</h1>
  <center>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png/A548FF" alt="" id="certImg"></div><!-- Column -->
    <div class="col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png/A548FF" alt="" id="certImg"></div><!-- Column -->
    <div class="col"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200.png/A548FF" alt="" id="certImg"></div><!-- Column  -->
  </center>
</div>

</div><!-- cert Acting as row -->
```